# Problems installing devtools in R

Tags: r, http-status-code-403, devtools

I am running on a linux vm. I have tried to install a number of things to fix this problem but have had no success.

While trying to install devtools via install.packages("devtools") I get the following error at the end: "cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'"

Any help would be great. I tried installing stringi first and it is giving me the same error.

Comment: Have you tried different CRAN mirror? Like `install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`? You might want to try some other [mirrors](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) too

Comment: I tried this and still no luck.